# Safely store AWS IAM User Keys (Access and Secret) created by IaC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I've the following setup:

1. Infrastructure is setup using AWS CDK;
2. I've one Stack/Environment (Production, Staging...);
3. Each Stack has a different S3 Bucket (used for website hosting);
4. I've a Stack that creates an IAM User (used by CI/CD);
5. CI/CD in this case is GitHub Actions (deploy every time a merge to `main` happens);
6. The IAM User has only put rights to all the Buckets (deploy means put the assets in the Bucket);

What is the best way to store/handle the keys for that user?

I started printing it in the Outputs but it is not secure. Everyone can see it (if they've access to the logs of CI/CD for example).

I've been suggested to store them in SSM: it works but you can't create it as SecureString so it would be just a String.

I've also taken a look into Secrets Manager: it also works and seems to be more secure (not sure if my feeling here is valid though).

Any ideas/opinions here?

Thanks!

---

In the code it looks something like:

```
// Production Stack
const bucket = new Bucket(this, "Bucket", {
  bucketName: "production",
});

// Staging Stack
const bucket = new Bucket(this, "Bucket", {
  bucketName: "staging",
});

// IAM Stack
const user = new User(this, "User", {
  userName: "ci-cd-user",
});
const userAccessKey = new AccessKey(this, "UserAccessKey", { user });

// This is just an example, I go through all the available Buckets
bucketProduction.grantPut(user);
bucketStaging.grantPut(user);
```

Comment: What CI/CD tool do you use? Is it in AWS? Please update your question with more detail, then reply here so I can see it's been updated. The answer is different depending on this information.

Comment: Hey @Tim, I've just updated with more information: CI/CD is GitHub Actions and deploy means putting assets in the Buckets.
Does it help or do you need more details?

Comment: Personally I would create the IAM user or at least their access key manually then transfer credentials to where they're needed in Github, rather than storing them inside AWS. If you must store them inside AWS then parameter store or secrets manager would be my pick, either is fine so long as they're encrypted. I would probably restrict who can view the credentials wherever you decide to store them.

Comment: Hummm.. Got it.
I was trying to automate as much as possible the process but indeed manually tackling the keys makes sense. Would Roles, through federation, be the best solution?
What I mean: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/security-hardening-your-deployments/configuring-openid-connect-in-amazon-web-services

Comment: Roles are almost always a better option than IAM credentials. I don't know anything about github actions, but if it can assume a role then take that option. Just make sure the role is properly secured so only github actions can assume the role.

Comment: Thanks! I will add it as an answer here as soon as I can properly try it with Roles.

Comment: Looks like to get it to assume the role you just specify the role with no credentials, and it uses OIDC, so should be a lot more secure. https://github.com/aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials

Comment: Yeah @shearn89, I tried it yesterday and it works like a charm. I wasn't full aware of it or how it works... I will summarize my findings in the answer.
Thanks for pointing it out ‍♂️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a while but I finally wrapped my thoughts around it here: https://dev.to/viniciuskneves/use-aws-through-github-actions-without-secret-keys-32eo

The ideia is to use [OpenID Connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_create_oidc.html) to [connect with GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/security-hardening-your-deployments/configuring-openid-connect-in-amazon-web-services) and then have a Role that can be assumed by GitHub Actions and perform the deployment (same policies I would give to GitHub Actions user).

Using AWS CDK the solution looks like the following:

```
const provider = new OpenIdConnectProvider(this, "GitHubProvider", {
  url: "https://token.actions.githubusercontent.com",
  clientIds: ["sts.amazonaws.com"], // Referred as "Audience" in the documentation
});
const role = new Role(this, "Role", {
  assumedBy: new OpenIdConnectPrincipal(provider, {
    StringEquals: {
      "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:aud": "sts.amazonaws.com", // "Audience" from above
    },
    StringLike: {
      "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:sub":
      "repo:<ORGANIZATION>/<REPOSITORY>:*", // Organization and repository that are allowed to assume this role
    },
  }),
});

bucket.grantPut(role); // Creates policy
```

After that we need to update GitHub Actions to use this instead of our user keys:

```
...
permissions:
  id-token: write
  contents: read # This is required for actions/checkout (GitHub documentation mentions that)
...
- name: Configure AWS Credentials 
  uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1.6.1 # Version at the time of this writing
  with: # We are loading keys stored in secrets
    role-to-assume: arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT>:role/<ROLE-NAME> # You can specify the role name when creating it or AWS will automatically generate one for you
    aws-region: eu-central-1
- run: npm run deploy # Just an example
```